# Get ID3 from stream on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've a problem to retrieve id3 tag on iOS with MPMoviePlayer.
It's from an internet stream (Shootcast server).

```
- (void)getNameTrack  {

    if ([player timedMetadata]!=nil && [[player timedMetadata] count] > 0) {

        MPTimedMetadata *firstMeta = [[player timedMetadata] objectAtIndex:0];
        MPTimedMetadata *secMeta = [[player timedMetadata] objectAtIndex:1];


        NSLog (@"Value: %@ and key: %@ and keyspace: %@ and timestamp: %f", firstMeta.value, firstMeta.key, firstMeta.keyspace, firstMeta.timestamp);
        NSLog (@"Value: %@ and key: %@ and keyspace: %@ and timestamp: %f", secMeta.value, secMeta.key, secMeta.keyspace, secMeta.timestamp);

    }
}
```

The caller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(getNameTrack)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

When I launch app, this is the result in NSLog :

```
2014-08-13 19:08:21.972 radio[814:60b] Value: GZA Feat. Governor Two's - Highway Robbery and key: title and keyspace: comn and timestamp: 1.018776
2014-08-13 19:08:21.973 radio[814:60b] Value: &artist=GZA%20Feat.%20Governor%20Two%27s&title=Highway%20Robbery&album=Legend%20Of%20The%20Liquid%20Sword&duration=240251&songtype=S&overlay=no&buycd=&website=&picture= and key: publisher and keyspace: comn and timestamp: 1.018776
```

When The track changes, I've the wrong id3 tag:

```
2014-08-13 19:09:16.180 radio[814:60b] Value: Smothered Mate and key: TIT2 and keyspace: org.id3 and timestamp: 54.752653
2014-08-13 19:09:16.182 radio[814:60b] Value: az_B42233_Grandmasters_GZA.jpg and key: TXXX and keyspace: org.id3 and timestamp: 54.752653
```

I don't know why "keyspace" changes from "comb" to "org.id3"